# Exact created date and time using dataloader with using where condition

Tags: apex, data-loader

how to extract exact created date and time using data loader with out using where condition?

Comment: What do you mean by "exact created date and without using where condition"? Can you be explain  more?

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't why you are asking 'without using the WHERE condition', because you would only use WHERE conditions when querying a subset of records. For example, if you only wanted to query on Opportunities where the name contained 'ABC' you would input the SOQL statement `SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Name LIKE '%ABC%'`

A very good starter into SOQL can be found here: http://www.sfdc99.com/2013/06/05/intro-to-soql-and-why-you-must-learn-it/.

2) To extract the exact date/time that a record was created, you simply select the field **CreatedDate** when using the Data Loader.

The format of the CreatedDate will be like so: yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ. More info can be found here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004680&language=en_US.

For example, the output will look like this: 2006-01-19T16:08:17.000Z.

So a SOQL to use to extract the CreatedDate from the Opportunity object would be: `SELECT CreatedDate FROM Opportunity`. And of course, you could also query a subset of opportunities by using `SELECT CreatedDate FROM Opportunity WHERE Name LIKE '%ABC%'`.

**Important to note:**

a) The CreatedDate is determined by the TimeZone user locale settings of the user credentials used to login to the Data Loader. For example, if person A has a New York TimeZone, as specified in the TimeZone field on his/her user record, the CreatedDate output will be a New York TimeZone. If person B has a London TimeZone, then the CreatedDate output will be a London TimeZone.

b) Also, the CreatedDate field *can* be bypassed. CreatedDate is a special type of field called a system field* and if a System Admin requires to insert data into Salesforce with a CreatedDate other than the date of insertion, then a case will need to be logged with Premier Support in order to be given this permission.

c) Once permission has been given, you can insert data into Salesforce with a CreatedDate other than the date of insertion. This only works on insert DML, it does not work on updates.

*Other examples of system fields are LastModifiedById, CreatedById and LastModifiedDate.